# generate uidNumber for Ldap posixAccount with LdapTemplate

Tags: java, ldap, spring-ldap

Has someone already encountered this error with the creation on a posixAccount in Ldap?

```
 javax.naming.directory.SchemaViolationException: [LDAP: error code 65 - object class 'posixAccount' requires attribute 'uidNumber']
```

Is there a smart way to generate a unique UidNumber delegating the creation to Ldap instead of taking care to find out the uniqueness? (like the identity column in SQL Server for exmple)

Thanks

Here the code I use:

```
public class LdapService {

//...
private LdapTemplate ldapTemplate;

public UserInfo save(final UserInfo user) {
    Name dn = buildDn(user);
    ldapTemplate.bind(dn, null, buildUserAttributes(user));

    // Update Groups
    for (String group : user.getGroups()) {
        try {
            DistinguishedName groupDn = new DistinguishedName();
            groupDn.add("ou", "groups");
            groupDn.add("cn", group);
            DirContextOperations context = ldapTemplate
                    .lookupContext(groupDn);
            context.addAttributeValue("memberUid", user.getUid());
            ldapTemplate.modifyAttributes(context);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return user;
}

private Attributes buildUserAttributes(final UserInfo user) {
    Attributes attrs = new BasicAttributes();
    BasicAttribute ocattr = new BasicAttribute("objectclass");
    ocattr.add("top");
    ocattr.add("inetOrgPerson");
    ocattr.add("posixAccount");
    attrs.put(ocattr);
    attrs.put("givenName", user.getName());
    attrs.put("sn", user.getSurname());
    if (user.getDisplayName() != null)
        attrs.put("cn", user.getDisplayName());
    attrs.put("userPassword", "{SHA}" + this.encrypt(user.getPassword()));
    attrs.put("mail", user.getEmail());

    return attrs;
}
//...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your server supports the modify-increment request control, an LDAP client could use that to increment an integer in one atomic operation. See also: [LDAP: Modify-Increment Extension](http://ldapmaven.com/2011/08/02/mastering-modify-increment/).

Comment: Your link return a 404 :(